# Geogig errors after install

Tags: gis

I've been trying to configure GeoGig on Windows 10 but am running into errors anytime I try to use a command. I seem to have been able to set the global user.name and user.email using the config command but was unable to run the below command. The same sort of error also comes up if I try to run geogig init.

````
C:\Users\first last\Documents\geo_trial>geogig config -l --global
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.loadLibrary(RocksDB.java:64)
        at org.rocksdb.RocksDB.<clinit>(RocksDB.java:35)
        at org.locationtech.geogig.rocksdb.RocksConnectionManager.connect(RocksConnectionManager.java:60)
        at org.locationtech.geogig.rocksdb.RocksConnectionManager.connect(RocksConnectionManager.java:39)
        at org.locationtech.geogig.storage.impl.ConnectionManager.acquire(ConnectionManager.java:61)
        at org.locationtech.geogig.rocksdb.RocksdbObjectStore.open(RocksdbObjectStore.java:121)
        at org.locationtech.geogig.rocksdb.RocksdbObjectStore.open(RocksdbObjectStore.java:110)
        at org.locationtech.geogig.rocksdb.RocksdbObjectDatabase.open(RocksdbObjectDatabase.java:85)
        at org.locationtech.geogig.repository.impl.RepositoryImpl.open(RepositoryImpl.java:121)
        at org.locationtech.geogig.repository.impl.GeoGIG.getRepository(GeoGIG.java:124)
        at org.locationtech.geogig.cli.GeogigCLI.newGeoGIG(GeogigCLI.java:269)
        at org.locationtech.geogig.cli.GeogigCLI.loadRepository(GeogigCLI.java:241)
        at org.locationtech.geogig.cli.GeogigCLI.loadRepository(GeogigCLI.java:236)
        at org.locationtech.geogig.cli.GeogigCLI.getGeogig(GeogigCLI.java:181)
        at org.locationtech.geogig.cli.porcelain.Config.runInternal(Config.java:99)
        at org.locationtech.geogig.cli.AbstractCommand.run(AbstractCommand.java:68)
        at org.locationtech.geogig.cli.GeogigCLI.executeInternal(GeogigCLI.java:532)
        at org.locationtech.geogig.cli.GeogigCLI.execute(GeogigCLI.java:368)
        at org.locationtech.geogig.cli.app.CLI.run(CLI.java:95)
        at org.locationtech.geogig.cli.app.CLI.main(CLI.java:113)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot determine JNI library name for ARCH='x86' OS='windows 10' name='rocksdb'
        at org.rocksdb.util.Environment.getJniLibraryName(Environment.java:66)
        at org.rocksdb.NativeLibraryLoader.<clinit>(NativeLibraryLoader.java:19)
        ... 20 more```
````

Comment: Check your JRE architecture: run "java -version", you should see "Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM". If not you probably need 64 bit jre.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick.

Comment: How do I install this - I'm having the same problem

Comment: `openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_232-8u232-b09-0ubuntu1~18.04.1-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)`
This is actually what I have but still no joy

Comment: Follow this link, https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html